# WPF Task Manager: Handling Refreshing CPU Load Value?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, taskmanager

I am currently somewhat new to c#/wpf (and coding in general). I decided to start another project, being a custom made "task manager" of sorts.

(While I use binding, this is NOT a MVVM project, so all answers welcome)

If you have ever opened task manager, you know that one of the main helpful tools it provides is a updating view of CPU/RAM/Whatever usage. Telling the user what percent of the resource they are using.

My problem is not getting the CPU percentage. I am unsure on how to refresh the text property for CPU load in the UI efficiently.

My first thought was that I should create a Background worker (which is probably correct) to separate the thread loads. However, I can't seem to wrap my mind on the solution to implement the background workers in a useful way.

The code is currently set up in this fashion:

1. When page is loaded, public BgWrk creates a new instance of it self.
2. Adds task to be called when ran.
3. BgWrk is ran.
4. New instance of method to be called is made.
5. Dispatcher is invoked on main thread to update UI.
6. Invoke consists of setting public string PerCpu (bound in other class, using INotifyPropertyChanged & all) on the return value of "grabber"'s CpuPerUsed.
7. BgWrk disposed.
8. Program loops (this is most likely the problem).

   ```
   private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {

       BgWrk = new BackgroundWorker();
       BgWrk.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(BackgroundWorker1_DoWork);
       BgWrk.RunWorkerAsync(); 

   }

   private void BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   {

       while (true)
       {
           CpuInfoGrabber grabber = new CpuInfoGrabber();
           Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action (() => Bnd.PerCpu = grabber.CpuPerUsed()));
           BgWrk.Dispose();
       }

   }
   ```

Again the code works, but it is WAY to slow due to the load of retrieving all of that data. Any suggestions on how to make this work well are appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I'd probably use a timer to poll the cpu usage. You can use a Timers.Timer which invokes its handler on a different thread. Within the handler you can marshal back to the gui thread and update your property

Comment: Also, make sure you do your heavy stuff outside of  the `Action` delegate method. I assume `grabber.CpuPerUsed()` is what you want to run on the background thread. With your current setup you're running that GUI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping you could use a timer to periodically poll for the CPU usage.

```
class Test
{
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;

    public Test( )
    {
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer
        {
            // Interval set to 1 millisecond.
            Interval = 1,
            AutoReset = true,                
        };
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
        _timer.Start( );
    }

    private void _timer_Elapsed( object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e )
    {
        // This handler is not executed on the gui thread so
        // you'll have to marshal the call to the gui thread
        // and then update your property.
       var grabber = new CpuInfoGrabber();
       var data = grabber.CpuPerUsed();
       Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke( ( ) => Bnd.PerCpu = data );
    }
}
```

Comment: I used both of these answers to fix the issue. Should've just payed more attention in debugging. The problem was that even though I was using background workers, I made a dumb mistake, putting a method call within the current dispatcher, causing the UI to run VERY slowly.

Comment: I would recommend using a [`DispatchTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a `ThreadingTimer` in WPF whenever possible.  It means you don't have to deal with cross-thread calls through the `Dispatcher`, you just update the properties directly.

Comment: I'll have to post my code, but I personally did not use Dispatch Timer. The only Dispatch I used was Dispatcher itself (Current.Dispatcher......). Frankly, you do not need the timer, given you have the logic correct for the threads. The multi-threading spreads the process out enough where I can update the current usage about 3-4 times on average (working on an EXTREMELY slow computer that it who knows how long). So as long as you do not base your method invocations on a UI's thread, you are probably going to be fine.

Comment: The nice thing with the timer approach is you can easily control the resolution without resorting to stuff like `Thread.Sleep` if you're running in a loop on a background thread. In reality you probably don't need to poll the cpu that frequently (maybe half a second to a second).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `Task.Run` instead of a `BackgroundWorker` in your case:

```
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Keep it running for 5 minutes
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(new TimeSpan(hours: 0, minutes: 5, seconds: 0));

    //Keep it running until user closes the app
    //CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    //Go to a different thread
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //Some dummy variable
        long millisecondsSlept = 0;

        //Make sure cancellation not requested
        while (!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            //Some heavy operation here
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            millisecondsSlept += 500;

            //Update UI with the results of the heavy operation
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => txtCpu.Text = millisecondsSlept.ToString());
        }
    }, cts.Token);
}
```

Comment: It would probably make sense in this scenario to mark the `Task.Run` delegate method as async, and then use `await Task.Delay( 500 )` instead of `Thread.Sleep` so you don't waste a perfectly good thread by making it wait. Unless of course you weren't using that to throttle but to simulate work.

Comment: I understand that - I'm just simulating a heavy operation.